SikuliX screen capture mode only shows part of my screen from which I can take a screenshot
I'm using SikuliX IDE version 2.0.5, when I try to use the Take Screenshot functionality I only get shown part of my desktop. Is there a configuration option I need to change so that I get the entirety of my desktop from which I can take a screenshot.
I only have a single screen laptop. 
Like in the image above I only get part of my screen to work with, is there a way to pan around or change the settings to see my entire screen?

My default display scaling was 150%.  When I changed the scaling to 100% and restarted the application, sikulix was able to see the whole screen and that resolved the issue. I'm not sure why this is the case, and if anybody could share some light on it, it would be great!
